# Choice function and well ordering of all set

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Show the following are equivalent:

1. Every set can be well-ordered
2. $\forall S[0\notin S\rightarrow\exists C:S\rightarrow\bigcup S\land(\forall Y\in S(C(Y)\in Y))]$

So I just prove the equivalence between:

1. X can be well-ordered
2. There is a $C:(P(X)\backslash \{0\})\rightarrow X$ such that $\forall Y\subseteq X(Y\neq 0\rightarrow C(Y)\in Y)$

I feel it is the two equivalance are very similar, but I'm not too sure these two can relate to each other and assist the proof of the first one.

Comment: Should "$\rightarrow 0$" be "$\rightarrow X$"?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out! Editted

Comment: The first statement is the Well ordering theorem. The second statement is saying that evey set has a choice function (which can easily be shown to be equivalent to the Axiom of Choice). Its easy to show the Well ordering theorem implies the Axiom of choice, but not so much the other way around. The proof in this direction is in most set theory text books.

Comment: $\not\in$ should be $\neq$.

Answer (score 1):

Each member of $S$ is a subset of $\bigcup S$, and the empty set is not a member of $S$. So $S$ is a subset of $P(X)\setminus\{0\}$. So you can just restrict your choice function on that to $S$.